# WP Capabilities to Add Media, Use Media, But Not Edit Them

Tags: uploads, media, capabilities

I just want to have role that can specifically adding media, use the existed media, but not edit OR delete them.

I was looking for the capability, but [I don't see it listed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

Or it's really impossible to do that?
How can I do achieve it programmatically?

Comment: You mean authors should not be able to edit media they have uploaded themselves?

Comment: the author should BE ABLE to,
1. Upload, Edit, Delete their own media
2. Only VIEW another media uploaded by someone else

So the authors can use it, but not delete it in media gallery.
Is it possible, and how can I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is default behaviour for the author role. So you don't have to do anything.

When an author is in the process of inserting somebody else's media in his post, it *looks* like he can edit the properties, but this is only true for that current post. If he changes, for instance, the `alt` attribute, he will get a different `alt` attribute only for his own post. You could try to prevent that in the media manager, but that doesn't make sense, because when the html is inserted into the post, the author can change the attributes anyway.

Comment: I didn't even notice that! Glad to hear that cjbj, thanks!